# How to create a dynamic/ self-adjusting table in html, which displays a database in excel/ spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to make an interface with html for a database (db) in Google-Spreadsheet. Therefore, I have to use Google-appscript. It should display the associated values of a searched TeamNumber. I wrote the search an the inputField and this part is working.
The kind and the amount of the values in the db can change (Maybe the value age will be added or status will be deleted). It would be great if the found values will be displayed among each other.

```
For Example:
(Values in the database)
TeamNumber MyComp FirstName Lastname Status   ParterComp FirstName LastName
  3                 John    Mueller  atwork                Jack     Sparrow
  5                 Ryan     Smith     -                   Ben       Howard
   .....

(html table --> if my search function get TeamNumber 3)
TeamNumber 3
MyComp
Firstname  John
Lastname    Mueller
...
```

I know how to make static tables in html but I have no idea how to make them dynamic.
I am new at coding and at this community so forgive me if a made a mistake or something is unclear.

I tried something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     
     <table id="DynamicTable">
     </table>
     
  </body>
  
  <script>
  
  // object == found row
  for (var i =0;i<object.length:i++){ 
      AddHTML +="<tr>"      

      for( var j=0;j<=i;j++){
          Addhtml += "<th>" +head[j].name + "</th>";
          Addhtml += "<td>" +data[j].name + "</td>";
      }
  
      AddHtml +="</tr>" ;  
 } 
  
  </script>
</html>
```

The real code is at the place where I work.
Am I on the right way?

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: Another problem is, that I don´t know how to link the javascript to the table.

Comment: Read on [client-to-server](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) communication in Google Apps Script, this should get you started

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261174/7215091

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix TH & TD in one row if you want a horizontal output like your DB example.
TABLE has fixed structure TR having TH children as 1 row header, then TR with TDs as next row, etc. If you put TD next to TH in same row and ending TR after, you get such a rotated result.

Here is a demo with data build from your values creating table structure as you wanted ?
Mind ticking accept button under voting if you like my answer...

```js
var AddHTML = "";
var object = getObject();
for (var i =0;i<object.length;i++){ 
  AddHTML +="<tr>"
  for( var j=0;j<object[i].head.length;j++){
      AddHTML += "<th>" + object[i].head[j] + "</th>";
  }
  AddHTML +="</tr>" ;  

  AddHTML +="<tr>"
  for( var j=0;j<object[i].data.length;j++){
      AddHTML += "<td>" + object[i].data[j] + "</td>";
  }
  AddHTML +="</tr>" ;  
} 
document.getElementById("DynamicTable").innerHTML = AddHTML;

function getObject() {
return [
  {
    head:["TeamNumber", "MyComp", "FirstName", "Lastname", "Status", "ParterComp", "FirstName", "LastName"],
    data:[3, "", "John", "Mueller", "atwork", "", "Jack", "Sparrow"],
  },{
    head:["TeamNumber", "MyComp", "FirstName", "Lastname", "Status", "ParterComp", "FirstName", "LastName"],
    data:[5, "", "Ryan", "Smith", "-", "", "Ben", "Howard"]
  }
];
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px; /* small tricks 2 make rounded table simply or */
}
th {
  text-align:left; /* centered looks ugly */
}
```

```html
<table id="DynamicTable" border=1>
</table>
```

Btw better would be DOM approach - something like:

```
table.appendChild(document.createElement("TR"))
tr.appendChild(document.createElement("TD"))
td.innerText = "something"
etc.
```