# Send HTML table data back to Google Sheets using Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-apps-script-addon

I'm using an example from [this website](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/06/10/google-apps-script-getting-input-data-from-a-dialog-box-in-google-sheets/)

I'm trying to add values from HTML table to a1 cells of my active spreadsheet. I have a feeling, that the function `runsies(values)` is not even called.

The problem is, that I have got nothing in logs. 
The ideal solution will be result of user choice in separated cells. For example: Orange 1, Blue 2 and etc in A1, A2 and etc

What I'm doing wrong?

**Code.js**

```
//--GLOBALS--

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();


function onOpen(e){
  // Create menu options
  ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Admin")
      .addItem("Test","test"))
    .addToUi();
};

function test(){ 
  //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("testUI")
    .setWidth(450)
    .setHeight(300);

  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select the relevant module and unit");


};
//--GLOBALS--

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();


function onOpen(e){
  // Create menu options
  ui.createAddonMenu()
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu("Admin")
      .addItem("Test","test"))
    .addToUi();
};

function test(){ 
  //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("testUI")
    .setWidth(450)
    .setHeight(300);

  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select the relevant module and unit");

};

function runsies(values){
  //Display the values submitted from the dialog box in the Logger and in the A1 cell of active sheet. 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([values])
  Logger.log(values);
};
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>

        <table>
          <col width="60">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <col width="50">
          <tr>
            <th></th><th><strong>Unit:</strong></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><strong>Module</strong></th>
            <th><strong>n/a</strong></th>
            <th><strong>1</strong></th>
            <th><strong>2</strong></th>
            <th><strong>3</strong></th>
            <th><strong>4</strong></th>
            <th><strong>5</strong></th>
            <th><strong>6</strong></th>
            <th><strong>7</strong></th>
            <th><strong>8</strong></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Orange </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="orange" value="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Blue </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="blue" value="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Green </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="green" value="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Purple </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="na" checked></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="3"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="5"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="6"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="7"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="purple" value="8"></td> 
          </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
        <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />


    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      function form_data(){
        var values = [{
          "orange":$("input[name=orange]:checked").val(),
          "blue":$("input[name=blue]:checked").val(),
          "green":$("input[name=green]:checked").val(),
          "purple":$("input[name=purple]:checked").val()
        }];
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt()).runsies(values);
        closeIt()
      };
      function closeIt(){
        google.script.host.close()
      };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Htm table look like that]

=======================================================

UPDATE

Based on @Cooper answer. I changed This `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt()).runsies(values);` to this  `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).runsies(values);` 
This helped and now I'm getting `{orange=1, purple=1, blue=1, green=1}` in A1

with that code `sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([values])`

How to separate this data in different cells?

For example:
In cell A1 get 1 not `{orange=1, purple=1, blue=1, green=1}`

*I think, I have the dictionary type data (in python its called that way) with this code.*

```
var values = {
          "orange":$("input[name=orange]:checked").val(),
          "blue":$("input[name=blue]:checked").val(),
          "green":$("input[name=green]:checked").val(),
          "purple":$("input[name=purple]:checked").val()
        };
```

*How to obtain only orange value?*

---

Dictionary code had a mistake:

```
var values = {
          "orange":$("input[name=orange]:checked").val(),
          "blue":$("input[name=blue]:checked").val(),
          "green":$("input[name=green]:checked").val(),
          "purple":$("input[name=purple]:checked").val()
        };
```

I was looking for that
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([values["orange"]])

Comment: Do you actually have two functions named onOpen and and test().  That's a problem every function must have a unique name.

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261174/7215091

Comment: @Cooper thx, but that didnt change a thing. Can u look if the function 'runsies(values)'? Is that function even called?

Comment: This `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt()).runsies(values);` should be `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).runsies(values);` and by the way google.script.host.close() doesn't work on webapps.

Comment: You would probably have been able to see that error in the Browser console.

Comment: You shoud take a look at that example it allows you to view and edit all of the spreadsheets in your account.

Comment: @Cooper it helped! I'm getting `{orange=1, purple=1, blue=1, green=1}` in A1. Thx a lot. Do u know a solution, to divide `sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([values])` into a1-a4. It will be like `sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([values{orange}])`?

Comment: sheet.getRange(1,1).setValues([[orange],[purple],[blue],[green]])

Comment: @Cooper it's not working. How to point to index. Like in python with `foo[0]`

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what your asking how about updating you question with a little more information.

Comment: @Cooper updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function runsies(values){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  sheet.getRange(1,1,4,1).setValues([[values.orange],[values.blue],[values.purple],[values.green]]);
  Logger.log(values);
```

};