# Create an interface to edit a Google Sheet externally

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Ggoogle Sheet for a company that recieves orders and displays them in a chart along with information like price, date recieved, order ID etc. I need to make an interface that allows me to both send orders to the sheet remotely, and edit them remotely. I thought of using Google Forms for this, but as far as I can tell there's no way to edit sheets like this, merely send the orders. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: hey there, I didnt find anything on Google. Searches containing the words "google script" and "interface" showed me results talking about user interfaces within google scripts, which isnt what I'm looking for.

Comment: You're looking for [tag:google-apps-script-web-application]. You can create ui inside sheets as well as outside as a remote web app. Search official  documentation guides page. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261174/7215091

Comment: A Google Form is usually better suited for end users of the sheet, often to collect their responses. Although easy to implement, it has limited capabilities. 

If you would like to not just add rows to a spreadsheet, but also edit or delete those rows, as well as other actions, you would need to take a deeper dive into Google Apps Script. I know it's not what you're looking for, but I'm afraid this is the best (if not only) way to build the interface you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make changes to a Google Sheet's spreadsheet you will need to use either [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) or [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).

If you want an easy implementation and you are not very experienced with the use of APIs I strongly recommend using Apps Script. As @TheMaster metioned, you can use the [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) of Apps Script to create an interface inside the spreadsheet or externally through the use of a remote [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

If however, you are looking for a more tailored function without the need of using a web app or an interface in the spreadsheet, you could get and modify all the data using [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) which would allow you to integrate these functionallities within any application (web, desktop, mobile app, etc).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: oh dear, I forgot to respond to this, I'm really sorry! I took a shot at making a web app, that seems to be the easiest method to use. I'm having some trouble with getting the script to work rn, but I'll ask if I need help, thank you!